# C++ matrix library with skip elements, skip rows and median operations

Tags: library, c++, matrix

I'm looking for a C++ matrix (array) library, which can:

1. Create a new matrix using only every Nth row of source matrix.
2. Create a new matrix using only every Nth element of source matrix.
3. Compute median value of all matrix elements.